# google email app and a web host switch: redirecting?

Tags: email, google-apps

I have an organization using google email app. They just switched hosts for their website and now the email is disabled because google doesn't have the right configurations for the new host of the web. How do I deliver the correct info to google to get the email enabled again?

Answer (score 0):

It is probably due to changes in DNS rather switching web hosting provider. You should read [the guide to setting up DNS for google mail](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=33352).